# I'm struggling with a Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have a tags-box, much like this site's tags-box for tagging questions.

Upon submitting my form, a JSON response allows me to show the user a dialog. In the case of this response, the dialog has some extra data, a frontendupdate (filled with fields and values to update) structure.

tags.getData() sends a JSON request to repopulate the options for the tagsbox.

And then tags.findBy() allows me to specify a "column" of tags' data and match a value to it. I'm trying to get findBy to fire AFTER getData is submitted. I know how I could do this with callbacks, but a Promise seems better here.

Unfortunately, `then()` seems to fire immediately after the Promise, and before the data is organized and I really don't understand why.

I've tried several variants, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

```
function(dlg) {
  var id = +dlg.EXTRA.FRONTENDUPDATE.PlaceID;
  var tags = $('.tags-pTitle').data("tagsbox");

  if ($("#PlaceID").val() != id && id > 0) {
    var goal = function() {
      return new Promise(function resolve() {
        tags.getData();
        resolve();
      });
    };
    goal().then(function() {
      tags.findBy('PLACEID', id);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You said **before the data is organized**, what is doing that organisation? You seem to be missing that check before you return `resolve()` in your promise

Comment: When you do console.log(tags.getData()) do you get output as promise?

Comment: This should probably be `tags.getData().then(data=> tags.findBy...` You are completely ignoring requests in it that are asynchronous here

Comment: @FrankFajardo `tags.getData` sends some ajax requests and then sorts the results into an array container. My mistake was thinking `tags.getData` would complete before resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tags.getData() returns a promise you can directly chain like this

```
function(dlg) {
  var id = +dlg.EXTRA.FRONTENDUPDATE.PlaceID;
  var tags = $('.tags-pTitle').data("tagsbox");

  if ($("#PlaceID").val() != id && id > 0) {
    tags.getData().then(function() {
      tags.findBy('PLACEID', id);
    });
  }
}
```